# Customized google maps marker icon not showing in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor, google-maps-api-3

Something strange ( at least for me) is happening. I have a partial view that is showing  a couple of google map markers. However as soon as I use my own customized icon if refuses to display. But when I give my route in the RegisterRoutes function of global.asax.cs for instance like so

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And if my partial view is in Index view ,it for reasons unknown to me decides to show itself? 
Why is this and how is this solvable?

Update (code):
This is my code in the partial view called MapResults.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geocoder;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        collectingData();
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {

        });      
   } 

    function codeAddress(location, name, contract) {
        var address = location;
        var infowindow;
        var image;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                     var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(returnImage(contract),
                      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
                      new google.maps.Size(30, 42),
                      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                      new google.maps.Point(40,45),
                      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
                      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                  //  icon: image,   only showing when registered in global asax
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,            
                });

          infowindow = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions(boxText(name, contract)));
                     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                     });
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }   
        });               
    }
```

These are my most important functions.

This is a view that is using my partial view

```
@model IPagedList<HospitalSearch.Models.Buildings>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Map";

}
         <div>     
            @Html.Partial("MapResults")
        </div>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <input id="adres" type="hidden" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StreetBuilding) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberBuilding) />  
  }

  </body>
<div class="pager">
    @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount)
</div>
```

Having it in RegisterRoutes will show as wanted otherwise it will not.
Update: 
It turns out RegisterRoutes is somehow getting the  "correct" url to my image. If I use a direct path say http://localhost:8080/Content/image.png  then everything is fine. 
However "Content/image.png" does not work. If I figure out what exactly happens I'll update of course.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in a partial view, it's possible that the path to your image for your custom marker is no longer valid.  How are you referencing your image?  It would be best to use the Url.Content helper method to get the path.

If this doesn't fix it, can you post more code?  HTML and the map javascript?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the respons let me update my post, I tested the code without it being in the partial view and still not working.

Comment: Is returnImage a separate javascript function?